# Ran out of memory during Redshift UNLOAD operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

This is the command I'm using:

```
unload ('select * from SPEC_BFO.CASE_HISTORY where (INTEGRATION_ID,LAST_OPERATION_DATE) IN (SELECT INTEGRATION_ID,max(LAST_OPERATION_DATE) from SPEC_BFO.CASE_HISTORY group by INTEGRATION_ID)') to 's3://use-s3-dwnam-qa/NAM/SPEC_BFO/CASE_HISTORY/VIEW_CASE_HISTORY/VIEW_CASE_HISTORY.' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/use-redshift-dwnam-qa' delimiter '|' PARALLEL OFF header ALLOWOVERWRITE gzip;
```

Getting this error:

```
('There is a problem:', InternalError('S3 Query Exception (Fetch)\nDETAIL:  \n  -----------------------------------------------\n  error:  S3 Query Exception (Fetch)\n  code:      15001\n  context:   Request ran out of memory in the S3 query layer.\n  query:     8163346\n  location:  dory_util.cpp:1083\n  process:   asyncrequest_thread [pid=112556]\n  -----------------------------------------------\n\n',))
```

Remote Script invocation failed, this script will halt.

Comment: It seems that you are wanting to perform the equivalent of a `DISTINCT ON`, which Redshift unfortunately does not support. You might be able to use a Window Function to achieve the same goal, without having to use such a complex `IN` statement.

Comment: Have you tried whether the query works without `PARALLEL OFF` parameter?

Comment: @botchniaque yes I tried with parallel off still it got failed

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the query is too complex to combine with an `UNLOAD` operation.

Try creating the output table first by using a `CREATE TABLE AS` command, then `UNLOAD` that table via `SELECT *`.